# Merge an existing Wordpress site into a Joomla site

Tags: wordpress, joomla, joomla-extensions

We have a Blog site developed with Wordpress. It has been online for 2 years.

We are trying to create a new site with Joomla. The tricky part is that we want the old wordpress blog site to be part of the new site. We don't just want to put a few links on Joomla site and point to Wordpress site. We want to remain the Wordpress blog functions in the new site.

Any suggestion on how to approach?

Thanks in advance,

Milo

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/blog-integration/6659

Comment: You can also export all info from wordpress (posts) to XML, and then import the data.

Comment: @ceejayoz How does the extension work with Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/blog-integration/6659

This is the right plugin that I am looking for. Now it is compatible with Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Install you Joomla site, then just migrate your wordpress blog in a sub directory ;). I've done this before, and found it works great without any problems.